# EfficientnetB1 :ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 185 layers into a model with 184 layers

Tags: python, pre-trained-model, efficientnet

Im getting error when im using

```
model = EfficientNetB1(weights="efficientnetb1_notop.h5", include_top=False)
```

after I have converted pretrained weights model.ckpt to efficientnetb1_notop.h5

please help

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your labelled data or data pretrained with labels?

`include_top=True` deploys the model exactly as it is.

Comment: i m using my labelled data because , when im  using weights from imagenet , my accuracy is stuck around 90% and i want to increase it to maximum

Comment: if you are using your data then you need to include_top = False . You need also add number of classes at the last step.